# Why a view nested in scrollview cannot display in the bottom?

Tags: android, scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this is my layout xml.I want the button can display at the bottom,but it doesn't happen.Who can tell me the reason?

Comment: try android:gravity="bottom" in LinearLayout.

Comment: I think you should make it clear whether the button will also scroll while scrollview scrolls.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `fillViewPort` in your `scrollView`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` in your button

change `orientation` also for `LinearLayout`

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

That's it, your problem is solved

Comment: Thangks for your solution.But I want to know why must change to android:orientation="horizontal" can expand the whole screen.

Comment: to know that please check documentation of LinearLayout and learn about horizontal and vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

you can add inside `RelativeLayout`.

> - its best approach when you have scrollview and one button in bottom.
> - Button should be outside from scrollview so when scroll button will be
>     visible at bottum of screen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAdd" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What will happen when the keypad pops up? The buttons will jump over the keypad - essentially blocking views in the scroll view.